# Does the SharedPreferences File get deleted when you Uninstalled?

Tags: android

I have a question as I am getting an Error in my code which I know how to fix if I get the answer to this question. When you uninstall your app that has a SharedPreferences file storing some values, does the file get deleted too or do you need to delete it manually with the method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it get deleted on app uninstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete the app, the SharedPreference also gets deleted. Another option is, Go into your Settings, find the app and click on Clear Cache and Clear Data. When you reopen the application, it will open like it was newly installed.

The files are manually deleted, so you need not worry about deleting it.

Answer (score 3):

> When you uninstall your app that has a SharedPreferences file storing some values, does the file get deleted too

Yes.

> do you need to delete it manually with the method?

No, in large part because there would not be any method to do this. Your code is not called when your app is being uninstalled.

Comment: Thanks! Was annoying me. Thank you for the knowledge also, now I know :)

Answer (score 0):

The default SharedPreferences is stored at:

```
/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_preferences.xml
```

or at `/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PREFS_NAME.xml`.

On uninstall of the application, the data folder (containing the sharedpreferences) gets deleted. This happens on the Clear data as well (as mentioned in the above answer).

Hope this helps!